# strstr() in friend array not working

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, syntax-error, strstr

I have this code, which takes data from MySQL of two users. And when i click on "remove" button it will erase the user from both friend array and results return back into database. But it doesn't work. Help me, please.

```
if (@$_POST['removefriend']) {
    $add_friend_check = mysql_query("SELECT friend_array FROM users WHERE username='$user'");
    $get_friend_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($add_friend_check);
    $friend_array = $get_friend_row['friend_array'];

    $friend_array_explode = explode(",", $friend_array);
    $friend_array_count = count($friend_array_explode);

    $add_friend_check_username = mysql_query("SELECT friend_array FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
    $get_friend_row_username = mysql_fetch_assoc($add_friend_check_username);
    $friend_array_username = $get_friend_row_username['friend_array'];

    $friend_array_explode_username = explode(",", $friend_array_username);
    $friend_array_count_username = count($friend_array_explode_username);

    $usernameComma = "," . $username;
    $usernameComma2 = $username . ",";

    $userComma = "," . $user;
    $userComma2 = $user . ",";

    if (strstr($friend_array, $usernameComma)) {
        $friend1 = str_replace("$usernameComma", "", $friend_array);
    } elseif (strstr($friend_array, $usernameComma2)) {
        $friend1 = str_replace("$usernameComma2", "", $friend_array);
    } elseif (strstr($friend_array, $username)) {
        $friend1 = str_replace("$username", "", $friend_array);
    }

    if (strstr($friend_array, $userComma)) {
        $friend2 = str_replace("$userComma", "", $friend_array);
    } elseif (strstr($friend_array, $userComma2)) {
        $friend2 = str_replace("$userComma2", "", $friend_array);
    } elseif (strstr($friend_array, $user)) {
        $friend2 = str_replace("$user", "", $friend_array);
    }

    $removeFriendQuery = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET friend_array='$friend1' WHERE username='$user'");
    $removeFriendQuery_username = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET friend_array='$friend2' WHERE username='$username'");
    echo "Friend was deleted...";
    header("Location: /$username");
```

Comment: or you could properly [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your database, reducing your problem to a simple `delete from friends where user_id=$x and friend_id=$y`. Probably 90% of that code is useless and a direct result of a bad DB design.

Comment: I wish but the array looks like this "friend1,friend2,friend3,friend4" and when i decide to unfriend friend2 it didn't work and it wouldn't work with your solution either

Comment: yes, because you're storing csv data in the db. if you'd normalized your design, each of those friends would be their own distinct/separate record, and trivial to edit/delete

Comment: by the way you can't do `header...` after any `echo`. you will get **Page content already sent** error...

Comment: **WARNING**: `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications as it's being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Comment: I'm 100% with Marc. Do not store comma-separated values in the database if you intend to use these in a relational capacity. They cannot be indexed in a useful way, they're extremely annoying to manipulate, and they're useless when it comes to even simple queries involving a `JOIN`. If you restructure it to adhere to proper [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) principles and observe the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) you'll have a much easier time here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify a lot your code this way:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/01c49/1

```
//somewhere prepare dbo connection like:
$dbh = new PDO("pgsql:host=$host;port=5432;dbname=$db;user=$user;password=$pass");

if (@$_POST['removefriend']) {

$sth = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE users 
SET users.friend_array=
CASE WHEN FIND_IN_SET( :friend ,users.friend_array) > 1 THEN
   REPLACE(users.friend_array , CONCAT(',',:friend),'')
WHEN TRIM(users.friend_array) = :friend THEN
   ''
ELSE REPLACE(users.friend_array , CONCAT(:friend,',','') END
WHERE username= :username 
   AND FIND_IN_SET( :friend ,users.friend_array) >0");
$sth->bindValue(':username', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(':friend', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();

$sth->bindValue(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(':friend', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();

header("Location: /$username");
```

But as @MarcB said it is better to redesign your database.